# SQL query to extract metadata based on two conditions in second dataset

Tags: sql

I have two data sets with the following format:

```
m -  acc | sra_study | bioproject | 
tax - acc | tax_id | total_count
```

Each row of `m` represents a biological sample (`acc`). The `tax` table represents which organisms (`tax_id`) were found in each biological sample (`acc`) and how many times they were observed (`total_count`).
The `tax_id` and `total_count` columns values are integers, while the rest of the columns are strings.

I would like to filter rows in `m` based on whether `tax_id=9606` is present with a `total_count > 10000000` AND `tax_id=2` is present with a `total_count>1000000` for a given sample (`acc`).

I have tried to do this with the following SQL query:

```
SELECT m.acc, m.sra_study, m.bioproject
FROM `nih-sra-datastore.sra.metadata` as m,
     `nih-sra-datastore.sra_tax_analysis_tool.tax_analysis` as tax
WHERE m.acc = tax.acc
  AND (tax.tax_id = 9606 AND tax.total_count > 10000000)
  AND (tax.tax_id = 2 AND tax.total_count > 1000000)
```

However, the query does not return any results. I suspect this is because of a problem with the syntax my SQL query.

Comment: tax_id will never be 9606 and 2 at the same time.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (_without errors_), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: tax_id=2 and tax_id=9606 in the same sample could be true, since there could be more than one tax_id found in a given sample

Comment: then look at my edited answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch to explicit `JOIN` syntax.

`OR` the `WHERE` clause conditions.

If you want a m.acc having *both* tax_id 9606 *and* 2 (in separate rows), do a `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT m.acc, m.sra_study, m.bioproject
FROM `nih-sra-datastore.sra.metadata` as m
JOIN `nih-sra-datastore.sra_tax_analysis_tool.tax_analysis` as tax
    ON m.acc = tax.acc
WHERE (tax.tax_id = 9606 AND tax.total_count > 10000000)
   OR (tax.tax_id = 2    AND tax.total_count > 1000000)   
GROUP BY m.acc, m.sra_study, m.bioproject
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT tax.tax_id) = 2
```

Comment: Your last suggestion is almost right! However, I would like filter so that total_count of tax_id=9606 is greater than 10 million and the value of tax_id=2 is greater than 1 million.

Comment: Oops, I didn't notice there were different numbers. Will edit.

Answer (score 0):

You have specified what appears to be a mutually exclusive condition in your where clause
`tax.tax_id = 9606 .. AND .. tax.tax_id = 2`

Modify Like

```
SELECT m.acc, m.sra_study, m.bioproject
FROM `nih-sra-datastore.sra.metadata` as m, `nih-sra-datastore.sra_tax_analysis_tool.tax_analysis` as tax
WHERE m.acc=tax.acc 
  AND ((tax.tax_id=9606 AND tax.total_count > 10000000) 
       OR 
       (tax.tax_id=2 AND tax.total_count>1000000)
      )
```